# Showing current value in select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, haml, html-select

I've got this field in my form:

```
    %select{ :name => "name", :value => "#{@r.name}" }
      %option{ :value => "name1" } Name1
      %option{ :value => "name2" } Name2
      %option{ :value => "name3" } Name3
```

And it currently always shows the first option regardless to the current value. I need it to select the correct value if there is one.

Comment: Use the `selected` option.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848032/select-tag-specifying-the-selected-option-or-moving-an-array-element-to-index

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using the Rails' helpers `select_tag` and `options_for_select`:

```
- options = [ ['Name1', 'name1'], ['Name2', 'name2'], , ['Name3', 'name3'] ]
- selected_option_value = @r.name
= select_tag 'name', options_for_select(options, selected_option_value)
```

Some documentation:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

---

If you still want to not use the Rails' helpers and use only HAML, in your case:

```
%select{ :name => "name", :value => "#{@r.name}" }
  %option{ :value => "name1", :selected => @r.name == 'name1' ? 'selected' : '' } Name1
  %option{ :value => "name2", :selected => @r.name == 'name2' ? 'selected' : '' } Name2
  %option{ :value => "name3", :selected => @r.name == 'name3' ? 'selected' : '' } Name3
```